# Proving there is a function in a noncompact set $A$ that is bounded yet does not attain its maximum

Tags: real-analysis

I'm not very good at abstract proofs, quite awful at it really, so I'm struggling a lot with this seemingly basic question in my textbook.

"If $A$ is a noncompact subset of $R^n$, show that there is a bounded continuous real-valued function on $A$ that does not attain its maximum"

If a real set $A$ is compact then, by the Heine-Borel Theorem, it must be closed and bounded. We are dealing with a real set $A$ that is noncompact thus it must either be open or unbounded (or both). The question states that the function we wish to find is bounded, real, and continuous.

Am I right to assume that what we need to find is a function that is bounded yet open? An obvious example of this would be $y=\arctan(x)$, which exists in the set $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. All other sigmoidal curves are also open, bounded, and never achieve their maximum. How would I answer this question with abstract proofing instead of by direct example?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367408/there-exists-a-continuous-function-that-satisfies-this-property?rq=1 works

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a metrizable compactification of $\mathbb R^n$ (*e.g.*, an $n$-dimensional sphere or torus) and let $d$ be a compatible metric on $X$. Since $X$ is compact and $A$ is not, $A$ is not closed in $X$. Let $p$ be a limit point of $A$ in $X$ which does not belong to $A$. Then the function $x\mapsto-d(x,p)$ is a bounded continuous function on $X$ which does not attain a maximum on $A$.

If you don't want to use a compactification then I guess you have to consider two cases, $A$ is not closed or $A$ is not bounded. *E.g.*, if $A$ is unbounded, use something like $x\mapsto\frac{-1}{1+d(x,0)}$.

Comment: Since the question states that we are looking for a bounded continuous real-valued function, is there any reason to consider if $A$ is unbounded? Wouldn't we only wish to consider if $A$ is not closed?

Comment: @Dylan All the question assumes about $A$ is that it is a noncompact set; an unbounded closed subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is noncompact, so yes, we have to consider that case. I don't see the relevance of your "since" clause; seems like a *non sequitur* to me. If $A$ is an unbounded closed set, then $A$ is not compact, so we have to find a bounded continuous real-valued function on $A$ which does not have a maximum value on $A$.

Comment: The question literally states, "show that there is a bounded continuous real-valued function on $A$". Do you not see the word bounded? Why would we need to consider an unbounded set when all we need is a bounded function?

Comment: @Dylan We don't get to choose a set $A$ that we like. A set $A$ is **given** to us in the problem, and all we know is that it is not compact. It may be bounded, it may be unbounded, we have no control over that. Regardless of whether $A$ is bounded (but not closed) or unbounded, we are required to find a function $f:A\to\mathbb R$ with certain properties (continuous, bounded, no maximum). Do the functions I gave as examples fail to satisfy those conditions?